# How to solve Deprecated Groovy Libraries plugin issue in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I see a notice like:

The following installed plugins are deprecated
Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries

"Pipeline: Deprecated Groovy Libraries Version588.v576c103a_ff86"

So, I go to "Installed" tab of "Plugin Manage" page, and try to remove it. It said
This plugin cannot be uninstalled, It has one or more instelled dependents.
"Pipeline","Pipeline:Declarative","Pipeline:GitHub Groovy Libraries"

Comment: There is some discussion on Google groups about it. The answer is to wait for the dependent plugins to switch their dependencies.  https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/5zLjVDw862E

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is:

Remove all the dependency at first.
"Pipeline","Pipeline:Declarative","Pipeline:GitHub Groovy Libraries"

But, I don't know what's the side effect, because these seems is not installed by me.